# Simplifying Powers of Fractions

Tags: limits

Say I have a fraction and I want to recursively multiply it by itself like so:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac ab\right)^x$$

where $\frac ab \leq 1$.

Is there a way in which I can simplify this so that it can be run in a computer program? I know that $(a/b)^x$ will approach zero so maybe there is some nice solution.

Comment: What you have here is a geometric series, and its sum can be easily calculated; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try to figure it out!

Comment: @player3236 Will you please convert your comment to an answer? It answered my question, thanks.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Happy to close :)